# Single-board low-power computer with gigabit port that has HW timestamping support

Tags: ethernet

I'm looking for a single-board computer with seemingly simple requirements:

- Gigabit ethernet port
- Ethernet port supports HW timestamping for PTP and NTP
- Low power usage
- Few GPIO pins
- The ethernet interface is not USB

I've searched for a while, but it's very annoying to search because HW timestamping and if the ethernet is connected to USB or not is rarely listed.

Maybe someone here knows any good devices?

Comment: Honestly, USB connected Ethernet is pretty rare. I would probably answer but I have no idea what you mean by HW time-stamping in the context of NTP.

Comment: @jan-dorniak
`Honestly, USB connected Ethernet is pretty rare.` The older Raspberry Pi's AFAIK all had ethernet connected to the USB bus?

Comment: `but I have no idea what you mean by HW time-stamping in the context of NTP.` Software such as `chrony` can utilize that feature for more accurate time synchronization, but I want it primarily for PTP.

Comment: And they are the exception. That they are popular doesn't really matter. That SoC was designed for settops... The SoC in Pi 4 still doesn't have an on-chip MAC, it uses a PCIe connected one.

Comment: do you mean something like a hardware RTC? In that case I could probably recommend something but it might end up in a 200 Euro range.

Comment: Well, if it can run Linux and has the hardware features I'm wishing for then sure, you can suggest something.

Comment: I will look for it in a few hours (still at work), but for now you can go through my profile to the Qt SBC answer, it would be likely similar hardware.